# In OS X ssh to vps I had changed the port in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, shut computer,

Tags: ssh, centos7, vps

That's about what happened, save for what had happened prior: I was following a tutorial that said to ssh to itself... somehow slightly differently but now I forget and can't track it down -- and I did.
I had also set PasswordAuthentication no.

The local prompt in Terminal is `mycomputer:~ user$` but window title is `user@mi.pad.dre.ds:~`. But searching up on it this seems to be normal enough behavior. My primary concern is with connecting through ssh right now.

So I try

```
$ ssh -vp xxxx root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xx [xx.xxx.xxx.xx] port xxxx.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 23.254.247.78:1231 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:LjPAnfLg4EL/B4CucIQEkAiloSREqKzGoYCpLnHsVdQ
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host '23.254.247.78' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/bitch/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/bitch/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: If you switched password authentication off, and you don't have any keys configured on the system as authorized keys to allow you to log in, then you're screwed. You need to get access to the console and log in there.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had generated a key and was just riding on that fact, despite not being quite ssh savvy just yet, so whether or not I really knew how to wield it.

I generated a key in my hosting client area and saved them public & private respectively, locally, then made a config file ~/.ssh/config in OS X:

```
Host <nickname>
HostName <hostnameip>
Port <pnum>
User <acct>
IdentityFile <path>
```

Cheers

Comment: Is this an answer, or are you just responding to wurtel's comment above?

Comment: And did you copy the public part of your key to your server before disabling password authentication?